# Code Igniter head tag not loading

Tags: html, codeigniter, libraries, head

```
<html>
<head>
    <?
        $this->common_lib->common_header_page("Online appointments at your favourite Beauty Salons and Spas.","Best Discounts and Offers at your Favourite Beauty Salons and Spas in Gurgaon. Search, Compare, Review and Book Online Appointments");
    ?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="body-inner home-page">
  <!--Header start -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <?php $this->load->view('common/main_navigation_bar');?>
      <!--/ Header start -->
      <!--banner sec start-->
      <?php $this->load->view('home/banner'); ?>
      <!--/banner sec end-->
    </div>
```

For some reason my head tag is not loading and the website loads after the banner sec has ended

Comment: How do you know your "*head tag is not loading*", what's "*banner sec*" and how does it end?

Comment: If `common_header_page` in Common Lib is **returning** something, you should probably **echo** it:  `<?=$this->common_lib->common_header_page("Online appointments at your favourite Beauty Salons and Spas.","Best Discounts and Offers at your Favourite Beauty Salons and Spas in Gurgaon. Search, Compare, Review and Book Online Appointments");?>`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with

```
use full <?php tag instead short tag <?
```

As your code shows you are using short tag on head tag.